# Oracle 10 UPDATE query

Tags: oracle

I get  **0 rows updated message** when I ran the query below.  Why? Any ideas?

```
Update salespersons set salespersons.salary = salespersons.salary * 1.12 
where salespersons.empid =
(SELECT salespersons.empid 
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM (SELECT s.empid employeeid,
                               s.ename employeename,
                               SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary Topprofit
                               FROM salespersons s
                               LEFT JOIN orders o ON s.empid = o.empid
                               LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON o.orderid = oi.orderid
                               LEFT JOIN inventory i ON oi.partid = i.partid
                        GROUP BY s.empid, s.ename, s.salary)
                ORDER BY Topprofit DESC)
         WHERE ROWNUM = 2
        ORDER BY Topprofit ASC)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1 and Topprofit is not null);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this Update statement? A description would help.

Answer (score 5):

The following SQL will never return any row:

```
select * from <whatever> where rownum = 2;
```

The `rownum` pseudo-column numbers the rows in the result set. The first candidate row before the `where` filter would get assigned a `rownum` of 1 and be discarded because of the where clause. The second candidate row would the again be assigned a `rownum` of 1 and be discarded, etc.

Also be careful with combining `rownum` and `order by` clauses. The default doesn't do what you want, it orders *after* the row numbers have been assigned. (So an `order by` after selecting a single row with a `rownum` filter doesn't make sense.) Please look at the [`ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/pseudocolumns009.htm) documentation for examples of how to do "top N" queries.

You can select a specific row number by "materializing" it in a sub-query:

```
select * from (
  select foo, bar, rownum rnk
  from some_table
  order by bar, foo
) where rnk = 42;
```

You'd also be better off filtering out the nulls earlier if nulls are at all a possibility (filter them out in the most nested query if you can). And the above trick doesn't work that well with `group by`, so using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions154.htm) analytic function would be more appropriate.

Assuming you do want to give a nice raise to the employee ranked 2<sup>nd</sup> by `Topprofit`, you could base your query on something like this:

```
SELECT
  s.empid employeeid,
  SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary Topprofit
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary desc) rnk
FROM salespersons s
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON s.empid = o.empid
  LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON o.orderid = oi.orderid
  LEFT JOIN inventory i ON oi.partid = i.partid
GROUP BY
  s.empid, s.ename, s.salary
HAVING
  SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary is not null
```

Wrap that in `select employeeid from (...) where rnk = 2` and you should be good to go.

Comment: The not null checks and `NULLS LAST` orderings can probably be avoided if the `LEFT` joins are converted into inner joins. I guess the Nulls only appear because of the `SUM()` over null values.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to order the salesmen by their sales success and find the (2nd) top. Then update that guy's salary by 12%.

I think the error is in line 3:

```
Update salespersons set salespersons.salary = salespersons.salary * 1.12 
where salespersons.empid =
(SELECT employeeid                               --- change this
...
```

But there are other issues, too, and the query can (and should) be further simplified by removing one nesting level and (as @Mat pointed out) the redundant `ROWNUM=2` and adding `NULLS LAST` in the ordering to avoid placing nulls first. I think this (the nulls first or last) was the reason that no rows were updated in the first place:

```
Update salespersons set salary = salary * 1.12 
where empid =
(SELECT employeeid
 FROM (SELECT s.empid employeeid,
              s.ename employeename,
              SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary Topprofit
              FROM salespersons s
              LEFT JOIN orders o ON s.empid = o.empid
              LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON o.orderid = oi.orderid
              LEFT JOIN inventory i ON oi.partid = i.partid
       GROUP BY s.empid, s.ename, s.salary
       ORDER BY Topprofit DESC NULLS LAST)                --added NULLS LAST 
 WHERE ROWNUM = 2 and Topprofit is not null) ;
```

and using window functions:

```
UPDATE salespersons 
SET salary = salary * 1.12 
WHERE empid =
(SELECT employeeid
 FROM (SELECT s.empid employeeid,
              SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary AS Topprofit,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary DESC NULLS LAST)
                  AS Rn
              FROM salespersons s
              LEFT JOIN orders o ON s.empid = o.empid
              LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON o.orderid = oi.orderid
              LEFT JOIN inventory i ON oi.partid = i.partid
       GROUP BY s.empid, s.salary) t
 WHERE Rn = 2 AND Topprofit IS NOT NULL) ;
```

---

You could also write the update like this:

```
UPDATE 
  (SELECT s.empid,
          s.salary,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary DESC) AS Rn
          FROM salespersons s
          LEFT JOIN orders o ON s.empid = o.empid
          LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON o.orderid = oi.orderid
          LEFT JOIN inventory i ON oi.partid = i.partid
   GROUP BY s.empid, s.salary
   HAVING (SUM(i.price * oi.qty) - s.salary) IS NOT NULL) t
SET salary = salary * 1.12 
WHERE Rn = 2 ;
```

Comment: I don't think your first two versions can return any rows because of the `rownum = 2` thing. Am I missing something because of nesting? (Last one does look good though, better than what I hinted at.)

Comment: @Mat: I rarely use Oracle and I avoid `ROWNUM` so you may be correct. That's why I added the `ROW_NUMBER()` way.

Comment: @Mat: Can you check this version of the 2nd query, would it work now?

Comment: I hope it does because that's essentially what I was working on :-) The `not null` test outside doesn't really work with the  `desc` ordering: the nulls will be first (and ranked). Does appear to work in a test here by moving the not null check to a `having` clause inside the nested query.

Comment: ... but that can also be resolved with `order by ... desc nulls last` without a `having` clause. Nicer.